# Why does Ping default to IPv6 for me?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, vpn

My homeserver running Debian 10 has at some point lost internet connection when being connected to Mullvad VPN via Wireguard.

I can `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping google.com -4` but I when I `ping google.com` it returns:

```
PING google.com(fra16s42-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:809::200e)) 56 data bytes
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
From dynamic-2a01-0c23-60be-c200-12c3-7bff-fe9e-4379.c23.pool.telefonica.de (2a01:c23:60be:c200:12c3:7bff:fe9e:4379): icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Port unreachable
```

It has never before defaulted to IPv6 and I assume that this might be the root cause for a bunch of problems.

`dig google.com` returns IPv4

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     222 IN  A   172.217.18.110
```

Normally I would assume that ping uses IPv6 because Mullvads DNS server returns only IPv6 but then dig should show that, right? Why does this happen?

Comment: try `nslookup` or `host` command instead of `dig`, then you'll see a better picture of what `ping` resolves host names to. In my experience, if there is ipv6 address available, ping uses it - that explains why `ping google.com` tries to ping the ipv6 address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `dig` only queries for `A` (IPv4 address) records. Try adding `AAAA` (the IPv6 address record type) to the command:

```
$ dig google.com AAAA
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     106 IN  AAAA    2607:f8b0:400a:806::200e
[...]
```

Or use `host`, which queries for both (and `MX` records as well):

```
$ host google.com
google.com has address 142.251.33.110
google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:400a:80b::200e
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

As for why `ping` is preferring IPv6 over IPv4: from the [source code for iputils version of ping](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/ping/ping.c), it looks like it just picks the first relevant address that `getaddrinfo()` returns. According to the [man page for `getaddrinfo()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo):

> There are several reasons why the linked list may have more than one *`addrinfo`* structure, including: the network host is multihomed, accessible over multiple protocols (e.g., both `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6`); or the same service is available from multiple socket types (one `SOCK_STREAM` address and another `SOCK_DGRAM` address, for example). Normally, the application should try using the addresses in the order in which they are returned. The sorting function used within `getaddrinfo()` is defined in RFC 3484; the order can be tweaked for a particular system by editing *`/etc/gai.conf`* (available since glibc 2.5).

[RFC 3484](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc3484) has been replaced by [RFC 6724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6724), but I'm not very knowledgable about either one (or the `/etc/gai.conf` file that can be used to override that policy).

If there's something flaky in your IPv6 connectivity, it may be that other programs besides `ping` are also following the `getaddrinfo()` order, trying to use IPv6, and that's causing trouble. Some programs (especially browsers) implement the ["happy eyeballs"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc8305) method (basically, try both versions and use whichever succeeds first), but other programs may not be that clever.

Comment: While this is nice to know, my problem is not that dig returns IPv4 but that ping uses IPv6 which fails. I might have worded my problem wrong: Ping has always used IPv4 for me and I would like to find out WHY it suddenly uses IPv6.

Comment: this actually does answer the last question - why ping uses ipv6 - because an ipv6 address is resolved for the hostname

Comment: Are you saying that if ping can use a IPv6 address it will? I am testing all of this on a second system which doesn't have the problem mentioned:
`host google.com` results in both an IPv4 and IPv6 but ping still tries to use IPv4. As it always has for me on any system I've ever used.

Comment: @decimo See my update.

Comment: Wow, ok, that gives me a lot of info on how to approach the problem. Thank you! Still weird, that my ping changed it's ways but whatever.